# Animating Children Of a Control after drawing some graphics on it

Tags: c#

I have a User Control which contains a panel by name of panel1. there is a  instruction in the `panel1_paint` which draws some lines on the panel,I am going to execute paint event in a windows form by line below :

**NOTE : DrawLines has defined in UserControl1.CS**

```
public void DrawLines()
{
    ...
    ...
            panel1.Invalidate();    
}
```

I don't know why this won't run , maybe it draws line and then panel makes a refresh and this make the panel to be  cleared.
So I changed my code to this :

```
public void DrawLines()
{
    ...
    ...
    panel1_Paint(this, new PaintEventArgs(panel1.CreateGraphics(),
         panel1.ClientRectangle));  


}
```

This works nice.it draws some lines in the panel, now the main part is :
there are some objects that they will create at run time on the panel as children . I want to move them over the panel (for example suppose there are fire particles) . so when I move (animate) them by `timer` , the lines which drawn by the `e.Graphics` of the Paint Event will be cleared and removed if any of those objects(particles) on the panel move over them.
So How can I avoid this ?! Is there any problem with my Invalidation ?
How can I have both, lines and moving particles on the panel ?
panel has done the graphics , but why by moving objects on it, the graphics will removed?

Comment: CreateGraphics() is the issue.  In the Paint() event use the supplied "e.Graphics" to draw and all should be fine.  Then you can use your original code of "panel1.Invalidate();"

Comment: can u Give me an example ?

Answer (score 1):

Here's how to use the supplied Graphics in the Paint() event:

```
    private void panel1_Paint(object sender, PaintEventArgs e)
    {
        Graphics G = e.Graphics;

        // ... use "G" to draw with ...
        G.DrawLine(Pens.Black, 0, 0, panel1.Width, panel1.Height);
    }
```

Then you can simply use:

```
panel1.Invalidate();
```

Comment: I had used that in my second code. I think there is a problem with double buffering....

Comment: Would need to see more code to understand the problem.  Basically using CreateGraphics() draws to a **temporary** surface which is why the drawings get erased when you pass controls over them.  The correct way is to use "e.Graphics" as shown above.

Comment: HMM , seems correct , I will check that by Double Buffering enabled.